# How to explode and find average of XYZ coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, explode

I have a column `XYZ` in a table which has `(x,y,z)` coordinates stored in it. I would like to find the average of that column.
When I try the following SQL,

```
SELECT AVG(xyz) FROM table1
```

it gives me the average value of only `x -coordinate`. I am trying to use the result in `php` code.

So I also tried

```
$xyz = mysql_query("SELECT xyz FROM  `notes_two` where id=".$id);
list($leftx,$topy,$zindexz) = explode('x',$xyz);
```

But I still do not know how to find the average of all the rows of the column `xyz`

Here is my [table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62208/1/0)

Comment: What do you think is the average of the `xyz` row? The `xyz` column is `varchar`

Comment: Does CAST help? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: of course `CAST` does not help. What would you cast it to? int? That would give you 1 integer. Considering you have 3 integers (x,y,z), you'll want to first calculate the center of all those locations. Then take an average of all those centers. Tricky math :)

Comment: Is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

With query you can do as

```
Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(xyz,'x',1) as x ,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(xyz,'x',-2),'x',1) as y ,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(xyz,'x',-1) as z from table1
```

check the demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62208/10

Then using regular PHP u can get the average of each row.

OR directly with query you can do as

```
Select 
AVG(x) as AVG_X,
AVG(Y) as AVG_Y,
AVG(z) as AVG_Z
from
(
  select
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(xyz,'x',1) as x ,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(xyz,'x',-2),'x',1) as y ,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(xyz,'x',-1) as z from table1
 )t1
```

check demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62208/11

Comment: how do I store these 3 average values to a php variable? with while loop ?

Comment: Yes u can execute the query and fetch them and store in PHP variable.